# How to set Browser Window size in Rspec (Selenium)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, integration-testing

I am working on Ruby On Rails integration test using **capybara, Selenium**.

How to set testing Browser Window Height and Width?

I searched, but nothing work well for me.

I tried following code.

```
page.execute_script('$(window).width(1200)')
```

Can any one. please.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `resize_to(width, height)` method that is part of the selenium webdriver.

For example, the following would make the browser 100px wide and 200px tall:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(100,200)
```

Comment: I also refined this solution as follow: `page.br...00) if page.driver.browser.respond_to? 'manage'`, which allows the tests to run in headless mode

Comment: `page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1280,800) if page.driver.browser.respond_to? 'manage'` # runs only when :selenium is the javascript_driver

Answer (score 6):

It help's for me:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, 
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: {
      "chromeOptions" => {
        "args" => %w{ window-size=1024,768 }
      }
    }
  )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Building onto Justin Ko's helpful answer:

How about importing a `responsive_helper` module to your spec file? For example,

```rb
module ResponsiveHelpers

  def resize_window_to_mobile
    resize_window_by([640, 480])
  end

  def resize_window_to_tablet
    resize_window_by([960, 640])
  end

  def resize_window_default
    resize_window_by([1024, 768])
  end

private

  def resize_window_by(size)
    Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(size[0], size[1]) if Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.respond_to? 'manage'
  end
end
```

[Check it out!](http://railsware.com/blog/2015/02/11/responsive-layout-tests-with-capybara-and-rspec/)