# Change default Capybara browser window size

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

So, with respect to integration testing using Capybara and RSpec, I know I can do this:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(x,y)
```

per [How to set Browser Window size in Rspec (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802363/how-to-set-browser-window-size-in-rspec-selenium) for specific RSpec tests, but is there a way to do this globally so that every test that is affected by media queries doesn't have to define this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could define that under `before(:all)`

```
describe "Test" do
  before(:all) do
    ...
    ...
    page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(x,y) #Mention it here
  end

  it "should find everything" do
    ...
  end

  after(:all) do
   ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Then I need to do that in each spec file right?  How do I do it for *everything*?

Comment: You can use RSpec.configure to include or extend modules in your examples, then place your before :all/:each in the module you're including/extending: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module

Answer (score 38):

A proper way to do it for all js tests is to add following inside `spec_helper.rb` `RSpec.configure` block

```
config.before(:each, js: true) do
  Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
end
```

to maximize the window. Change to `resize_to(x,y)` to set any window size.

**EDIT**: If you happen to be using Poltergeist the correct way to do it is

```
config.before(:each, js: true) do
  Capybara.page.driver.browser.resize(x,y)
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Capybara and Poltergeist: `undefined method 'manage' for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Browser:0x007fd4e76ec828>`

Comment: Hey @tirdadc what version are you using?

Comment: ok, I can see there's no manage for Poltergeist but there is a way to resize, updating the answer!

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps due to a recent change in Capybara, what worked for me was:

```
before do
  Capybara.page.current_window.resize_to(x, y)
end
```

Comment: This is the only one doing at least something currently, but I get Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError error. I tried both poltergeist and webkit. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, anyone has idea what's wrong?

Comment: @Aurimas You can try to change your driver, try to use `js: true` in your spec

Answer (score 10):

For test runtime in ***Capybara 2.2.4*** version you can achieve this by doing

```
before do
  handle = Capybara.page.driver.current_window_handle
  Capybara.page.driver.resize_window_to(handle, width, height)
end
```

Or

```
before do   
  Capybara.page.current_window.resize_to(width, height)
end
```

**If you get Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError: Capybara::Driver::Base#current_window_handle YOU MUST CHANGE YOUR DRIVER FOR EXAMPLE USE *JAVASCRIPT DRIVER*!**

```
before do   
  Capybara.page.current_window.resize_to(width, height)
end

scenario js: true do
  # your test here
end
```

Answer (score 2):

@tirdadc if you're using Poltergeist, you can add something like this to your `rails_helper.rb` file:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  options = {
    # js_errors: true,
    # cookies: true,
    window_size: [320, 568] # iphone 5
  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

Comment: Tried this ```Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false, window_size: [1280, 800])``` and worked.