# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, admin

I'm having trouble with my test for a method which lets an admin user promote other users to admin by the click of "Promote to Admin". It lies in my controller, I'm writing a feature test for it. I'm using Rails 5.1.4.

```
  def promote
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   if @user.toggle!(:admin)
    flash[:success] = "User is promoted to admin."
    redirect_to root_path
   else
    flash[:notice] = "Can't promote."
    redirect_to root_path
   end
  end
```

This is the test:

```
describe "Promotion" do
 before do
  login_as(User.create!(name: "lala", email: Faker::Internet.email, 
  password: "lalala", admin: true))
  visit users_path
 end

context "to admin" do
 it "promotes user to admin" do
  click_link("Promote to Admin", :match => :first)
  expect(current_path).to eq user_promote_path
 end
end
end
```

It gives me the error: Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible link "Promote to Admin"
which I think is because I'm not accessing the right page, trying to log in as admin is perhaps not working.
Any suggestion would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason for your test failing is that you don't appear to have created any other users beyond the one you're logging in as.  If you haven't then there wouldn't be any users to show "Promote to Admin" links for.  You can always save the page or just do `puts page.html` to make sure what you think is on the page actually is.

A second issue with your test is that you should never use the `eq` matcher with current_path.  You should be using the Capybara provided path matcher of you want stable tests

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(user_promote_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed the problem was about not having any other users. But also the user_promote_path was not the right solution since my page actually just redirects back to the users_path after the promoting.

Comment: @katjass Ok - then rather than checking the path your test should check for whatever visible change occurs to indicate the user has been promoted - text saying it has, icon change, class change, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that you're on the right page, you can do some debugging with:

- `save_and_open_page` (opens your browser)
- `save_and_open_screenshot` (takes a screenshot and opens it)

If it's all good, maybe Capybara can't find the link : Is it a screen size/responsive issue ? If yes, you can configure the window size that Capybara uses (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390071/change-default-capybara-browser-window-size#26977863))

If the test still does not pass, maybe the link is not visible by default ?
You can add to option `visible: false` in `click_link` to precise that.