# Rails4/Capybara - use the value of the test window width/dimensions inside a test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

In my ruby on Rails 4.2 app, I am injecting in the view in a data-attribute a piece of information calculated based on window.width(). For the sake of the question simplicity, I make here the assumption it is equal to just window.width()

**view.js**

```
var screen_width = window.width();
$target.attr('data-size', screen_width)
```

I would like to test in rspec/cpabayar (webkit driver) that the target elment has the right data-size.

For my tests i currentrly use a module to be able to set the size I want

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# Helpers to help test responsive and screen resize
  # config.include ResponsiveHelper
  config.include ResponsiveHelper, type: :feature
```

**/spec/responsive_helper.rb**

```
module ResponsiveHelper

  def resize_window_to_flattened_window
    resize_window(1200, 480)
  end

  def resize_window_to_mobile
    resize_window(375, 627) # apple iPhone 6
  end

  def resize_window_to_tablet
    resize_window(960, 640)
  end

  def resize_window_default
    resize_window(1024, 768)
  end

  private

  def resize_window(width, height)
    case Capybara.current_driver
    when :selenium
      Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(width, height)
    when :webkit
      handle = Capybara.current_session.driver.current_window_handle
      Capybara.current_session.driver.resize_window_to(handle, width, height)
    else
      raise NotImplementedError, "resize_window is not supported for #{Capybara.current_driver} driver"
    end
  end

end
```

I have a test that test that the right value is inside data-size attribute of the Target in the view:

**view_features.spec.rb**

```
describe "view behaves appropriately in terms of video size" do
  resize_window_default
  visit view_page_path(deal)
  expect(page).to have_css('#target[data-size="1024px"]', visible: :visible)
end
```

The thing is I have a lot of those tests above for various size (mobile1, mobile2, ipad... laptop...)

Currently as you see above, I must myself put "hard-coded" in the test 1024 px (here: `have_css('#target[data-size="1024px"]`') as, of course if I have put resize_window_default, it means the window.width is 1024 and the test should assign 1024px to Target's data-size.

But I'd like to scale this to many tests without hardcoding it where each time I would not need to hard-code the value of the width I expect.

Is there a way to just ?

1. extract/get the width of the screen used by capybara ?

This would be "universal", and independent of my Responsive Helper. It would work in any test, whether I use Responsive Helper or not.

I mean Capybara has a method resize_to which enables to re-set the width, so Capybara must have somewhere a way to get the width output/value itself ?

Something that would go like:

**view_features.spec.rb**

```
width_set_by_capybara = Capybara.screen.width
expect(page).to have_css('#target[data-size= width_set_by_capybara]', visible: :visible)
```

2. if 1 is not possible, is there a way to pass as a parameter or sth alike from my ResponsiveHelper module to my test file, sth that will enable me to re-use the value of the width I have just set ?

Something that would go like:

**/spec/responsive_helper.rb**

```
 module ResponsiveHelper
   def resize_window_default
      resize_window(1024, 768)
      width_set_by_capybara = "1024px"
   end
```

**view_features.spec.rb**

```
expect(page).to have_css('#target[data-size= width_set_by_capybara]', visible: :visible)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using driver specific methods for any of this (any time you're using Capybara.current_session.driver. you're probably doing something wrong).  Rather you should be using Capybara's window api - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Window

To get the size of the current window

```
Capybara.current_session.current_window.size
```

To set the size of the current window

```
Capybara.current_session.current_window.resize_to(width, height)
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the answer. I see what you mean. I'll try without. but just to make sure I correctly understand your suggestion: for sure I'll try inside the rspec test itself (called "view_features.spec.rb") to NOT use Capybara.current_session.driver. See next comment

Comment: But are you also saying that I should not use Capybara.current_session.driver inside the module /spec/responsive_helper.rb ? I had taken inspiration from https://railsware.com/blog/2015/02/11/responsive-layout-tests-with-capybara-and-rspec/ and they use Capybara.current_session.driver.
See next comment

Comment: I wonder why they use it then ?  Is it because maybe it's a more "generic"/"high-level" way that works for other drivers (selenium...) and maybe for a SINGLE test suite you might have multiple platforms inside your test CI (appium using selenium for example, others using webkit) and they need to provide for both drivers.

Comment: it generated an error: "# Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
# Capybara::Driver::Base#current_window_handle" When I do in my LCI "gem list" I can read capybara (2.13.0, 2.7.1), capybara-webkit (1.14.0, 1.11.1). I did not find many having the same issue apart from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390071/change-default-capybara-browser-window-size/26977863 but I could not find sth to make it work. and I tried ading js: true on the test but did not change anything. Any idea?

Comment: Upgraded capybara via bundle update capybara and now I have capybara (2.18.0, 2.13.0, 2.7.1)
capybara-webkit (1.14.0, 1.11.1) so my app using capybara 2.18 but i am still getting the error "Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
  Capybara::Driver::Base#current_window_handle'. I am cautious about upgrading to Release Candidates 3.0 as they're not sable (https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara/) Should i do it? Is it what is causing me this error according to you ?

Comment: What's really strange is that i get this error when I use "Capybara.current_session.current_window.size" in my test but using "handle = Capybara.current_session.driver.current_window_handle" in my current module does not create an error...weird

Comment: Figured it out even though i am not expert enough to completely understand the Why: using width = Capybara.current_session.current_window.size[0] inside the test generated the error mentioned in my comments above. To solve this I had to do let(:widthsize)                      { Capybara.current_session.current_window.size[0] }, and reuse this widthsize after. this works. The fact to use it inside a let(:) seems to have done the difference in my case, maybe related to some specifics of my tests.

Comment: it was throwing me Capybara::Driver::Base#current_window_handle even if I was not indeed explicitly using current_window_handle. I was just using the copy-pasted "Capybara.current_session.current_window.size"

Comment: @Matthieu the only way that would happen is if you're using a driver that doesn't support windows (rack-test for instance), or a REALLY old version of capybara-webkit, but then you shouldn't be doing anything with windows in a test that's using rack-test

Comment: I am using capybara 2.18 gem so not old i think

Comment: Anyway it worked with let, so I'll keep this and your suggesiton worked. i will also try to improve my /spec/responsive_helper.rb file by using directly   def resize_window(width, height)
    Capybara.current_session.current_window.resize_to(width, height)
  end and this way not use "current_session.driver." as you adviced

Comment: @Mathieu `capybara-webkit` not `capybara` -- they are different.  `capybara-webkit` is a headless driver that can be used with `capybara`, the latest version of `capybara-webkit` is 1.15.0

Comment: I have in my gem list capybara (2.18.0, 2.13.0, 2.7.1) capybara-webkit (1.14.0, 1.11.1). I think they're pretty recent/up-to-date

Comment: @Matthieu `gem list` just shows the gems that are globally installed in your system, it doesn't tell you want gems your project is using.  To tell what gems and versions your project is using you'd need to look in the Gemfile.lock or run `bundle list`

Comment: ok did not know: bundle list gave me: capybara (2.13.0) and capybara-webkit (1.14.0). I try to bundle update relatively often so I'm not too behind:)

Comment: @Mathieu Both of those are over a year old, so you probably want to update them.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that method in [here.](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/window.rb)

```
##
# Get window size.
#
# @macro about_current
# @return [Array<(Integer, Integer)>] an array with width and height
#
def size
  @driver.window_size(handle)
end
```

It seems that you can get the window dimensions calling:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.size
```

Comment: thanks I'll try and keep you updated if it works. Will also try to improve with Thomas Walpole suggestion.